How to train a model using a text dataset
I want to create an AI model that generates text. Specifically, BDD Gherkin cucumber scenarios and step definitions based of input of a user story.
User story with BDD Gherkin cucumber example
For example.
User story (Input): I want to add products to my shopping basket on an e-commerce website to make a purchase.
Output: Automatically create the test case scenarios and step definitions
Test case scenarios:

Scenario 1: Validate that user can add one item to cart
Scenario 2: Validate that user can remove one item from cart

Test case scenario 1:

Given the user launch and login e-commerce application with  and 
Then the user navigates to items page.
And the user selects and click on a .
And the user clicks the “Add to cart” button.
Then the user should navigate to the Shopping Cart page.
And user should validate  in Shopping Cart Page has been successfully added.

Test case scenario 2:

Given the user launch and login e-commerce application with  and 
Then the user should navigate to the Shopping Cart page.
And the user finds  in shopping cart and click “Remove from cart” button.
Then user should validate that  in shopping has been successfully removed.

I have created a sample dataset that contains user stories mapped to scenarios and step definitions.
Dataset
From my current understand, the logic is that: I want to train a model based of the dataset of existing user stories and scenarios. After the model has been trained, I want to input a user story, and the model should come up with a suitable scenario with step definitions.
I am new to machine learning and has only done some form of supervised learning, regression. From some research, I would need to use some NLP techniques to process the dataset. From then on, I am pretty lost. I've seen some people talking about using ChatGPT to train of the dataset or something.
What would be a good way to do this project.
Essentially, I want to find out how to train a model using text so that the model can receive text and output text.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Based on my reading on your problem, very likely you don't have to train or tune your own model. Most of the foundation models should do a good job on it. All you need to do is probably just working on a good prompt. Describe your problem clearly to llm and give some good/bad examples. The only question is that if you want to fully automate the test case generation based on your input or not. If that's the case you will need to configure and make the api calls instead of doing it from UI (such as ChatGPT).
